# Angular4 Grouping an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, grouping

I am trying to groupby an array of objects w.r.t to one property of the object. What is the best way to acheive it? 
sample:

```
{ 
name: "India",
capital: "New Delhi",
cities:[{
name: "city1",
state:"state1"
},
{
name:"city3",
state:"state2"
}
....
{
name:"city56",
state:"state1"

}]
 }
```

What's the best way to display it grouped by state? Should I use pipes or group the array using typescipt? Is there grouping pipe available in angular4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ready to use pipe collections for Angular2+ which include `groupBy` pipes. Two possible examples are:

### [ng-pipes](https://a8m.github.io/ng-pipes/)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | groupBy: 'state'">
```

### [angular-pipes](https://danrevah.gitbooks.io/angular-pipes/)

```
<div>{{ arrayObject | groupBy: 'state' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) like this:

```
_.groupBy(myCityList, 'state')
```

Note that `myCityList` is the internal list that has the `state` property, like so:

```
const myCityList = [
    {
        name: "city1",
        state:"state1"
    },
    {
        name:"city3",
        state:"state2"
    },
    {
        name:"city56",
        state:"state1"
    }];
```